# Grease Pencil "nothing to erase" error

Tags: modeling, grease-pencil

So I'd been using the grease pencil with no issues before, and now as I try to write/draw with it, I get the "nothing to erase" error as if I was trying to use the eraser tool. I'm not, it happens with the "Annotate" tool: [image: my life is so sad]

Something else that happens that is a bit hard to explain is: I'm using a laptop and a screen tablet. If I'm tabbed out of blender, looking at my laptop, and then draw using the grease pencil, it works, but as soon as I'm tabbed back into blender (from the first stroke with the pencil) it stops working and the Annotate tool acts like an eraser again. Is there any way to fix this?

(Not sure if it matters, but while trying to sculpt earlier, my tools would subtract while the + button was active, and add when the - was active. Idk if Blender is freaking out or if my tablet's pen has something going on?)

Anyways, thanks in advance!